# How do we design identity management systems in Ethereum?

Tags: contract-design, design-patterns

I’ve read Ethereum will make possible cryptographically verifiable identities that are integrated with the Ethereum client, and thus not requiring any password or logins.

Does this presuppose the the user is using the Mist browser? Are there any proposed design patterns we make apps for the regular web that leverage some of the cryptographic niceties that Ethereum offer (mappings, for instance).

Comment: define "cryptographically verifiable identity"?

Comment: are you talking about a reverse turing test?

Comment: i'm referring to the statement that there's no need to log in to dapps

Comment: i'm sorry for being a bit unclear. i found a video example of the identity handling functionality i was referring to: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ij5tGo8cp80 (starts at 6:50)

here we have a button that changes it's appearance and function based on the account we have selected in mist. I'm trying to understand how to use this in my dapp project.